# React Formik Field removes name attribute from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

## Background

I am trying to get my html semantics correct whilst using Formik. All seems to work well but when I check the dom on an input the `name` attribute is missing. From reading the docs I guess this shouldn't happen, I should be able to just add the `name` attribute with no issues.

## My code

```
<FieldColumn key={props.id}> {/* this is just a styled component called FieldColumn */}
  <Field
    {...props}
    component={component}
    value={values[key] || ''}
    onChange={(value: string): void => onInputChange(key, value)}
    onBlur={(): void => onInputBlur(key)}
    errorMessage={touched[key] ? errors[key] : undefined}
  />
  <Spacer spacing={{ mobile: Spacings.medium }} />
</FieldColumn>
```

Where props has name. I've also just added it Directly as name on the Field component
But the result is always the same.

[image]

Other Attributes like `inputmode="email"` and `type="email"` work fine (they are also added to the props above).

## Question

So what am I doing wrong that the name is stripped from the DOM?

Comment: Could you post the whole scope of the component?

Comment: I can't see in doc there is something like `FieldColumn`. Are you using anything else in apart from formik?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Field column is just a named styled component. its just a div

Comment: The `name` attribute in the Field is responsible for `Formik` to know what part of your state you're updating. Could you post the whole scope of the component just to see the bigger picture?

Comment: @PrateekThapa sorry I think I have it. The Component Iuse inside Component is not built to handle the attributes from Formik properly.